# Android Studio : How to get name of current selected product flavor?

Tags: android, svn, gradle, android-productflavors

I have 2 flavors customized. 
Right now, I want to collect different resources from svn for each flavor, 
and it would be easy to handle if there is a way to get name of current selected product flavor, but I have no idea how to do that..

Or Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current flavor in gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621183/how-to-get-current-flavor-in-gradle)

Comment: @RahulChaurasia umm.. I see.. so how do I know which flavor is selected by the answer on the link? I still don't get it. it looks like just iterate all the variants..

Comment: When using gradle from the command line, there is no "selected" flavor you either build on or the other, e. g. `./gradlew assembleFlavor1Debug` or `./gradlew assembleFlavor2Release`, etc. And in Android Studio just open the "Build variants" dock and select the variant you want. To open press Ctrl+Shift+A (on Linux) and type "build variants", or hit Alt twice and select it (left edge of the screen, below the center).

Comment: As Rahul said, this is a duplicate, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34679933/4350967).

Answer (score 0):

get current `taskStr` and check with your flavor's name is contains `<br/>`

```
//get current task Str <br/>
String taskStr = getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString();<br/>

// True if current Flavor is "yourFlavorName"<br/>
taskStr.toLowerCase().contains("yourFlavorName")
```