# Check selected build on gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Is there a way we could get the selected build variant on the Gradle file when we compile?

I would like to use inside the *dependencies* task the following code:

```
buildVariant = awesome code to get the buildVariant selected flag 
if (buildVariant == A)
compile project(':moduleA')
else
compile project(':moduleB')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy supports java code so you can use something like this:

```
def getCurrentFlavor() {
Gradle gradle = getGradle()
String  tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()

Pattern pattern;

if( tskReqStr.contains( "assemble" ) )
    pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
else
    pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( tskReqStr )

if( matcher.find() )
    return matcher.group(1).toLowerCase()
else
{
    println "NO MATCH FOUND"
    return "";
}
}
```

source: [How to get current flavor in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621183/how-to-get-current-flavor-in-gradle)

Comment: You sir are a life saver. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Click on **Build Variant** which is at the left bottom side of Android Studio

It has a list of all build variants available

[image]

Comment: This is not what I am asking Amey.