# Android app versioning with multiple dimensions

Tags: android, gradle

I have problem with versioning Android application with multiple flavors and dimensions.
Project is configured like this:
Three dimensions:

```
flavorDimensions "company", "app", "server"
```

And multiple flavors:

```
productFlavors {
    company1 {
        applicationId "com.com1"
        dimension "company"
    }
    company {
        applicationId "com.com2"
        dimension "company"
    }
    app1 {
        applicationId "com.app1"
        dimension "app"
    }
    app2 {
        applicationId "com.app2"
        dimension "app"
    }
    sever1 {
        dimension "server"
    }
    server2 {
        dimension "server"
    }
```

To ignore some of the possible mixes, everything is done by doing setIgnore in gradle file

```
    variantFilter { variant ->
    def names = variant.flavors*.name
    if (names.contains("app1") && names.contains("sever2") ||
            names.contains("app1") && names.contains("sever1") ||
            names.contains("app2") && names.contains("company1") ||
            names.contains("company") && names.contains("server2")) {
        setIgnore(true)
    }
}
```

Everything is based on the [Advanced Android Flavors](https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-2-enter-flavor-dimensions-4ad7f486f6) series

So with that configuration, I do not know how to set different versions for different variants. Something like

```
company1app1 {
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0." + versionCode
}
company2app1 {
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.1." + versionCode
}
company1app2 {
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0." + versionCode
}
company1app2 {
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0." + versionCode
}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution: in `defaultConfig` add lines

```
versionCode computeVersionCode()
versionName computeVersionName()
```

`computeVersionCode()` and `computeVersionName()` can be arbitrary functions, for example:

```
def computeVersionCode(){
    String flavor = getCurrentFlavor()
    if (flavor.startsWith("company1app1")){
        return 2
    } else if (flavor.startsWith("company2app1")){
        return 5
    } else if (flavor.startsWith("company1app2")){
        return 8
    } else if (flavor.startsWith("company2app2")){
        return 2
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
```

`getCurrentFlavor()` is defined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44183316/5312102