# How to access gradle defaultConfig in a parent gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to access the defaultConfig which define in a subproject (app--> build.gradle) into a parent build.gradle but seems to be not working OR I am doing something wrong. Actually I need to access the buildvarient which I define in a defaultConfig of app build.gralde file.

app build.gradle:

```
android {
    def buildTypeV // define here to update in loop

     dependencies.metaClass.allCompile { dependency ->
        buildTypes.each { buildType ->
      //      "${buildType.name}Compile" project(path: ":${dependency.name}", configuration: buildType.name)
            buildTypeV=buildType.name
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
         versionNameSuffix "${buildTypeV}"
    }
```

From parent build.gradle file, I am doing like this to access versionNameSuffix:

```
gradle.buildFinished {

     def buildV=${project.android.defaultConfig.versionNameSuffix};
        println "buildV:::: $buildV"

    }
```

It seems to be a wrong way to access the defaultConfig as the build is failing it. Can someone give me an idea of how I can access It properly?

Error which I see on console:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not find method $() for arguments [build_8kbbn8x9zcumz6eqfx8ryt61s$_run_closure2$_closure3@77596dd9] on root project 'df-backpack' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

In my subproject define application variant:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        def flavor = variant.name
        outputFileName = "../app-${flavor}-final.apk"
    }
    variant.assembleProvider.get().doLast getbuilder(variant.name.toLowerCase())
}
```

// in parent build.gradle:

```
 project('hpnurse') {
        buildStr=it. android.applicationVariants.all;
        //also tried like this 
        //it.variant.buildType.name;

    }
```

Comment: Please, post also the error you are getting.

Comment: Question updated with console error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `project.android` you referring to the caller project, in your case, the parent project. Instead, you should refer to your Android subproject.

From the parent project you can access a specific subproject by name using `project(name)`.

```
gradle.buildFinished {
    project('app') {
        def buildV = it.android.defaultConfig.versionNameSuffix
        println "buildV:::: $buildV"
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine, Can I know it is possible to get the buildVariant of subproject in a parent in the same way?

Comment: @user565 you can get all the variants combining your build types and your flavors

Comment: Sorry i am not getting this. Can you please show how I can access variant.name in parents project? I have updated my questions

Comment: @user565 To get the current variant you can do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34679933/4237609

Comment: Have no luck by using this. I have added getCurrentFlavor in parent build.gradle file and when try to access it it is showing empty value in response.

Comment: @user565 I never had the need to get the current variant so I don't have a ready answer honestly. Have you tried searching other answers on SO for that?

Comment: Yes, try all others as well.