# Android Gradle read flavour file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

My app has three flavours (`flavourOne`, `flavourTwo` and `flavourThree`) and each flavour has its own `versions.properties`

I need, at build time, to retrieve a value in that file.

If I do this:

```
defaultConfig {
    ....
    def file = file("${project.projectDir}/src/flavourOne/version.properties")
    // I can now access to the file and obtain the value that I want.
}
```

But in the above solution, I need to explicitly set the path to the file. Since I want the file that is contained I would like to do something like:

`def file = file("${project.projectDir}/src/../version.properties")` and dependending of the selected flavour that file would be transformed into:

```
def file = file("${project.projectDir}/src/flavourOne/version.properties")
def file = file("${project.projectDir}/src/flavourTwo/version.properties")
def file = file("${project.projectDir}/src/flavourThree/version.properties")
```

Instead, what the above does its to set the file to `${project.projectDir}/version.properties`

How can I read the specific flavour file at build time?

Comment: I think this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30621515/2199001

Comment: @Chris Thanks. Within that question I've found a way to achieve what I needed.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help. You could now post a solution to help others that come across your question.